# How to force my Html.DropDownlist to have flexible size base on its content length

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code which display  a drop down list inside my asp.net MVC web application:-

```
<div><span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.stateID)</span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.stateID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.ResourceState>)ViewBag.States).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.DISPLAYSTATE), 
        Value = option.RESOURCESTATEID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (Model != null ) &&  (option.RESOURCESTATEID == Model.stateID)
    }), "All") <i class=" icon icon-blue icon-star-on "></i>
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.stateID)
```

Currently the drop downlist contains text that is short 4-5 characters, but seems that the drop down list will always have a fixed size, and most of the dropdown size not being used as follow:-

[image]

So my question is whether I can make my drop down list size flexible , to fit the text it contains , so that in this case I can utilize the screen better ?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can make it flexible by using `.change` event handler.

First you've to store the selected text to some other element. I've used a hidden input here.

```
<input type="hidden" id="tmpwidth"/>
```

Now after storing the selected value to a hidden input, you should set the width of the `select` with the width of the `#tmpwidth`, which is the width of the current selected element.

This can be achieved with the following `jQuery` code

```
  $(function(){
    $("select").on("change", function(){
        $("#tmpwidth").html($('select option:selected').text());
        $(this).width($("#tmpwidth").width()+30);
    });
  });
```

Note that I'm appending 30 to the width of the temporary hidden input because here 30 will be the width of the down arrow of the `select` element

Hope this may help.

Finally here is the working fiddle

[`Fiddlelink`](http://jsfiddle.net/8rL3v/1)

Comment: but the dropdown list will not re-size again if i select short text , then long text..

Comment: @johnG check the updated fiddle. It seems like hidden input does not give correct width when resized again. I've tried with a `div` and it's working fine.